# Encrypt decrypt html content from CKeditor in PHP

Tags: mysql, codeigniter, encryption

Using CodeIgniter & MySQL

My users are creating personal content in CKEditor.

I want to encrypt this content and store it encrypted in MySQL.

Decryption key  or whatever is needed will be manually inputted by the user on time of logon and will be valid during his session.

How i should develop such a mechanism in PHP? (PHP version >= 5.4)

Additional Info:

-Content are medium/klarge posts in HTML
-Must be encrypted in MySQL with as much reassurance to the user of safety

Comment: You should probably ask a more specific question

Comment: [disclaimer: my page in progress] Something like this: [http://www.secretdiary.org/](http://www.secretdiary.org/)? It's just a small project I have in mind which I'll release at some point (when I learn how to use git properly). I'm using `mcrypt_encrypt()` and `mcrypt_decrypt()`. [This question is also very relevant about mcrypt_decrypt()](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7292658/938236)